# Laravel querying model relations

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-4

I'm still struggeling with the laravel Models. At first I tried doing it all using the tables, but thats not smart, I'll miss out on lots of the laravel functions.

I have the following setup

- ProjectTwitterStatus links the projects and the twitter statuses.
- TwitterStatus has all the details of a twitter status and has a unique ID ('posted at' datetime of tweet is among the details)
- TwitterRetweets has the ID of the TwitterStatus - the actual retweet - and the tweet ID of the retweeted status
- TwitterReplies has the ID of the TwitterStatus - that is the actual reply - and/or the user ID if not a reply to a status but to a user.

*What I want?* To get for each date (`DATE(datetime)`) the count of the statuses, retweets and replies, using the laravel model relations.

These are the models.

```
class ProjectTwitterStatus extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'project_twitter_statuses';

    protected $softDelete = true;

    public function twitterStatus() {
        return $this->belongsTo('TwitterStatus');
    }

    public function project() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Project');
    }
}

class TwitterStatus extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'twitter_statuses';

    public function twitterRetweet() {
        return $this->hasMany('TwitterRetweet');
    }

    public function twitterReply() {
        return $this->hasMany('TwitterReply');
    }

    public function twitterUser() {
        return $this->belongsTo('TwitterUser');
    }

    public function projectTwitterStatus() {
        return $this->hasMany('ProjectTwitterStatus');
    }
}

class TwitterRetweet extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'twitter_retweets';

    public function twitterStatus() {
        return $this->belongsTo('TwitterStatus');
    }       
}

class TwitterReply extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'twitter_replies';

    public function twitterStatus() {
        return $this->belongsTo('TwitterStatus');
    }

}
```

I got the count of the twitterStatuses using this:

```
$twitterStatuses = TwitterStatus::has('projectTwitterStatus')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(datetime)'))
    ->get(array(DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS tweets'),DB::raw('DATE(datetime) AS date')));
```

I tried for example this to get the retweet count added but that has no effect (a reference to the model apears in the object -> array().

```
$twitterStatuses = TwitterStatus::has('projectTwitterStatus')
    ->with(array('twitterRetweet' => function($query)
    {
        $query->count();
    }))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(datetime)'))
    ->take(10)
    ->get(array(DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS tweets'),DB::raw('DATE(datetime) AS date')));
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure how your intended solution is to be used - Assuming you simply want a count of the number of retweets related to twitterStatus?

```
$count = $twitterStatus->twitterRetweet()->count();
```

where `$twitterStatus` is an already retrieved model - not a collection.

if `$twitterStatus` is a collection to iterate through you can also eager load the related model using either `with()` or `load()`

Then you can iterate through each model in the collection - depends on how you wanted to use the results

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to be as clear as possible. What I want is a count of the retweets per day, and the retweet is linked to a twitterstatus_id.

Comment: sorry. So for each tweetstatus return the number of retweets per day? or total per day for all?

Comment: No problem, happy with all the help I can get. I want to return the total of tweets, retweets, and replies per day for a project.